# Browse Ubuntu source code directory

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have Installed Ubuntu 12.04 On Virtual Box. How to browse the source code directory? What is the commands on terminal to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An Ubuntu installation comes fully compiled - You won't find the source code in an installed Ubuntu.

To view the kernel code, go to the [Linux GitHub repository](http://www.github.com/torvalds/linux). To look at ubuntu-specific code, go to the [Ubuntu Launchpad code site](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu).